# Append itertools.product() results to variable in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to append every possible two-digit combination to the end of each string in a list.

The strings are each eight characters, and the digits should replace the seventh and eighth characters.

I am using `itertools.product()` to generate these two-digit combos, but I am not sure how to then append these combinations to strings. I tried using `join()`, but that sandwiches the string between each of the two digits.

My next attempt is below but doesn't work because you *cannot concatenate `'str'` and `'itertools.product'` objects*.

```
for p in passwords:
    candidates += list(p[:6] + itertools.product(string.digits, string.digits))
```

So, passwords looks like this

```
['american', 'japanese']
```

and the output should be

```
['americ00', 'americ01', 'americ02', …, 'japane98', 'japane99']
```

Comment: What does `l` and your `list` look like? And what are you trying to do by appending that to candidates in every iteration?

Comment: The list contains candidate passwords, so each one is just an eight character string. I want these new character/digit combinations to be added to the candidates list.

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the *input* data and an expected result.  If ```list``` contains one string, how many strings will be in the result?  Please avoid  using Python keywords and function names as names for your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just counting, the product isn't necessary  This could be abbreviated to:

```
 lst = ['american', 'japanese']
 candidates = ['{}{:02d}'.format(e[:6], i) for e in lst for i in range(100)]
```

Which is alanalgous to the loop

```
candidates = []
for e in lst:
    for i in range(100):
        candidates.append('{}{:02d}'.format(e[:6], i))
```

If really want product for one reason or another:

```
['{}{}{}'.format(e[:6], i, j) for e in lst for i, j in itertools.product(string.digits, string.digits)]
```

This can also generalize to a product with more arguments

```
[e[:6] + ''.join(pr) for e in lst for pr in itertools.product(string.digits, string.digits, string.digits)]
```

Comment: I think you have too many string.digits, you can also use repeat `[ele[:6]+"".join(tup) for ele in passwords for tup in product(digits,repeat=2)]`

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding this right, you want to create a list of candidates for each password. in that case, you could use something like below, where the replacements are calculated only once, and all the candidates are comma separated values:

```
import itertools
import string

candidates = []
replacements = ['%s%s' % (x, y) for x, y in itertools.product(string.digits, string.digits)]

list_of_l = ['american', 'japanese']
for l in list_of_l:
    candidates += [l[:6] + repl for repl in replacements]

>>> print candidates
['americ00', 'americ01', 'americ02', 'americ03', 'americ04', 'americ05', 'americ06', 'americ07', 'americ08', 'americ09', 'americ10',
'americ11', 'americ12', 'americ13', 'americ14', 'americ15', 'americ16', 'americ17', 'americ18', 'americ19', 'americ20', 'americ21',
'americ22', 'americ23', 'americ24', 'americ25', 'americ26', 'americ27', 'americ28', 'americ29', 'americ30', 'americ31', 'americ32',
'americ33', 'americ34', 'americ35', 'americ36', 'americ37', 'americ38', 'americ39', 'americ40', 'americ41', 'americ42', 'americ43',
'americ44', 'americ45', 'americ46', 'americ47', 'americ48', 'americ49', 'americ50', 'americ51', 'americ52', 'americ53', 'americ54',
'americ55', 'americ56', 'americ57', 'americ58', 'americ59', 'americ60', 'americ61', 'americ62', 'americ63', 'americ64', 'americ65',
'americ66', 'americ67', 'americ68', 'americ69', 'americ70', 'americ71', 'americ72', 'americ73', 'americ74', 'americ75', 'americ76',
'americ77', 'americ78', 'americ79', 'americ80', 'americ81', 'americ82', 'americ83', 'americ84', 'americ85', 'americ86', 'americ87',
'americ88', 'americ89', 'americ90', 'americ91', 'americ92', 'americ93', 'americ94', 'americ95', 'americ96', 'americ97', 'americ98',
'americ99', 'japane00', 'japane01', 'japane02', 'japane03', 'japane04', 'japane05', 'japane06', 'japane07', 'japane08', 'japane09',
'japane10', 'japane11', 'japane12', 'japane13', 'japane14', 'japane15', 'japane16', 'japane17', 'japane18', 'japane19', 'japane20',
'japane21', 'japane22', 'japane23', 'japane24', 'japane25', 'japane26', 'japane27', 'japane28', 'japane29', 'japane30', 'japane31',
'japane32', 'japane33', 'japane34', 'japane35', 'japane36', 'japane37', 'japane38', 'japane39', 'japane40', 'japane41', 'japane42',
'japane43', 'japane44', 'japane45', 'japane46', 'japane47', 'japane48', 'japane49', 'japane50', 'japane51', 'japane52', 'japane53',
'japane54', 'japane55', 'japane56', 'japane57', 'japane58', 'japane59', 'japane60', 'japane61', 'japane62', 'japane63', 'japane64',
'japane65', 'japane66', 'japane67', 'japane68', 'japane69', 'japane70', 'japane71', 'japane72', 'japane73', 'japane74', 'japane75',
'japane76', 'japane77', 'japane78', 'japane79', 'japane80', 'japane81', 'japane82', 'japane83', 'japane84', 'japane85', 'japane86',
'japane87', 'japane88', 'japane89', 'japane90', 'japane91', 'japane92', 'japane93', 'japane94', 'japane95', 'japane96', 'japane97',
'japane98', 'japane99']
```

Note that `list` is a python builtin, so it is not advised to use it as a variable name and hence I've used `list_of_l` to differentiate.